# pd.fillna or pd.DataFrame.loc for NaN values by function with condition

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, data-science

Hi everyone? i white a function to replace NaN values in DataFrame (1750 000 lines):

```
def Android_iOs_device_os_cange(df):
    def find_Android_brand(df):
        list_for_android = list(df[df['device_os'] == 'Android'].device_brand.unique())
        list_for_android.remove('(not set)')
        return list_for_android
    def find_iOS_brand(df):
        list_for_iOS = list(df[df['device_os'] == 'iOS'].device_brand.unique())
        list_for_iOS.remove('(not set)')
        return list_for_iOS
    for i in list(df[df.device_os.isnull() & df.device_brand.notnull()].index):
        if df.device_brand[i] in find_Android_brand(df) and pd.isnull(df.loc[i, 'device_os']) == True:
            df['device_os'][i] = df.loc[i, 'device_os'] = 'Android'
        elif df.device_brand[i] in find_iOS_brand(df) and pd.isnull(df.loc[i, 'device_os']) == True:
            df['device_os'][i] = df.loc[i, 'device_os'] = 'iOS'
        else:
            df['device_os'][i] = df.loc[i, 'device_os'] = '(not set)'
    return df
```

It fulfills its purpose, but but he replaced only 20,000 lines in 3.5 hours. I understand that the catch here is the for loop, but I don't understand how to make the function better. Who can advise anything?

I try to make it with function loc, but for my it always ended with

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'device_os'
```

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to do - replace Nan with what?

Comment: it might be helpful if you provide a sample of your dataframe as well. you can copy and paste the output from `df.head().to_dict()` into your question – this will allow people to run your code on a smaller dataframe. as @gtomer mentioned, it's not completely clear what you are trying to do but there is very likely a much simpler way to replace `NaNs` based on certain conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
def Android_iOs_device_os_cange(df):
    list_for_android = list(df[df['device_os'] == 'Android'].device_brand.unique())
    list_for_android.remove('(not set)')

    list_for_iOS = list(df[df['device_os'] == 'iOS'].device_brand.unique())
    list_for_iOS.remove('(not set)')

    df['device_os'] = np.where((df['device_brand'].isin(list_for_iOS)) & (df['device_os'].isnull()), 'iOs', df['device_os'])
    df['device_os'] = np.where((df['device_brand'].isin(list_for_android)) & (df['device_os'].isnull()), 'Android', df['device_os'])
    return df
```

The changes I made:
1) for the lists you do not need a function - this is time consuming running the function all over again
2) Used `np.where`. Loops is last resort in Pandas

Comment: i try your function, make some changes and it ends with this                   
 df['device_os'] = np.where((df[df['device_brand'].isin(list_for_iOS)]) & (df['device_os'], 'iOs', df['device_os']))
ValueError: Unable to coerce list of <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Series/DataFrame

Comment: which line gave this error?

Comment: i change to this import numpy as np
def Android_iOs_device_os_cange(df):
    list_for_android = list(df[df['device_os'] == 'Android'].device_brand.unique())
    list_for_android.remove('(not set)')

    list_for_iOS = list(df[df['device_os'] == 'iOS'].device_brand.unique())
    list_for_iOS.remove('(not set)')

    df['device_os'] = np.where((df[df['device_brand'].isin(list_for_iOS)]) & (df['device_os'], 'iOs', df['device_os']))
    df['device_os'] = np.where((df[df['device_brand'].isin(list_for_android)]) & (df['device_os'].isnull(), 'Android', df['device_os']))
    return df

Comment: (df[df['device_brand'].isin(list_for_iOS)]) & (df['device_os'], 'iOs', df['device_os'])

Comment: Yes first was The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: import numpy as np
def Android_iOs_device_os_cange(df):
    list_for_android = list(df[df['device_os'] == 'Android'].device_brand.unique())
    list_for_android.remove('(not set)')

    list_for_iOS = list(df[df['device_os'] == 'iOS'].device_brand.unique())
    list_for_iOS.remove('(not set)')

    df['device_os'] = np.where((df['device_brand'].isin(list_for_iOS)) & (df['device_os'].isnull(), 'iOs', df['device_os']))
    df['device_os'] = np.where((df['device_brand'].isin(list_for_android)) & (df['device_os'].isnull(), 'Android', df['device_os']))
    return df

Comment: ends with setting an array element with a sequence. in (df['device_brand'].isin(list_for_iOS)) & (df['device_os'].isnull(), 'iOs', df['device_os'])

Comment: ady your clean opinion ends with The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). in line df['device_brand'] in list_for_iOS

Comment: similar resalt error setting an array element with a sequence. in (df['device_brand'].isin(list_for_iOS)) & (df['device_os'].isnull(), 'iOs', df['device_os'])

Comment: I tryed to mark you ancer but i haven't enough reputation(